# Microsoft: Technical Do's and Don'ts of Naming Files/Folders?

Tags: windows

Edit: I realise my question wasn't specific enough. I meant this more as a question on what is the technical correct way to organise your folders because the person I was referring to told me when certain things are ordered like (1. 2. 3. 4.) it might take your computer more time to figure out the sequence and hence slowing your computer more if most of your files are named like that?

Something along those lines. Quite honestly I'm not so sure how specific I can get as I'm still quite confused by the entire thing. But basically the gist was I was told that there is a *certain* way one should name their files/folders (like not including dashes -) that follows the sequence Windows is used too!?

I am working with Microsoft Windows 10 and recently I was transferring files into my new hard-drive and someone told me that I was naming my files and folders wrong.

For starters, I like to name my folder "**1 - [name here]**" if I want it to be at the top of my list and I often add a lot of dashes in my file names when I am working on a design. It'll end up looking like "**Logo Design 1 - New Colour**" or something along the lines.

I'm not very tech savvy when it comes to this particular subject and a lot of googling has lead me more to people sharing different codes (??) than any explanation. So I was wondering if any of you might be able to offer me some solid tips on what's the best way to go about organising my folders?

Thank you!

Comment: Sadly this is pretty much down to personal preference. "Correct" depends entirely on your goal. If you want this thing to always be at the top of the list then what you are doing might work and if it works for you then it's cool. If you or someone you work with has specific requirements then they need to communicate them.

Comment: Do you want to know about how to make a folder structure (i.e. a tree of folders and subfolders), or are you interested in knowing about the technical problems that may arise (e.g. if a name contains certain characters)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm curious, did this person tell you what was wrong with the names?

Here, I'll focus on the technical side of folder (or file) names.

In an ideal world, we would be able to name folders anything we want them to. Whether that's the case for you depends on the operating system you use (Windows), and the your software.

*Most* software will deal fine with arbitrary folder names but here is a list of potential problems.

- Spaces in folder names
- Special characters such as emoji's, or other special characters e.g. &, ≠ or ±
- Characters that are not supported by the operating system (Windows in your case). These are / \ : * ? " < > |. But if you're on Windows already, it won't be possible to use those in the first place.
- Characters that are not supported by *other* operating systems. This may cause problems if you send a file to someone who uses a Mac, or Linux.
- If you work on Linux (and perhaps Mac too, I don't know) it's possible to have two names that only differ in case (e.g. *Folder* or *folder*). Sending those to someone who is on Windows will cause problems. Since you are on Windows yourself, this won't be a problem, I just added it for completeness.
- I've used (older) software that couldn't handle names starting with a number.
- Long filenames. A long time ago, filenames on Windows could be only 8 characters long (and have an extension of 3 characters). I doubt there's any software that can't deal with long names today, but maybe if you work in a bank, that might still be the case.

If you want to be *completely* on the safe side, I'd recommend using only a–z, 0–9, _ and -. That said, as long as you're not designing some corporate folder structure that needs to stay in place for years, just use whatever you see fit. If you find that it doesn't work, rename it.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I think you came close to what I was mostly confused about. Especially in regards to working with other software and stuff. I was just really confused as what an appropriate way to organise one's folders in whatever technical mumbo jumbo rules that goes along with an operating system. I really don't know this lingo and much about computers so colour me confused. I almost always name my folders starting with alphabets and on occasion add those "1 - My Work Files, 2 - My Photo Gallery" etc. To, like I mentioned, keep it above all the other folders.

Comment: To add: The person that told me it wasn't correct said it's because I'm confusing the sequence Windows searches for these files? Or something along those lines. They meant it well and was trying to teach me how to organise it better, but was basically saying that my way of organising was very messy in terms of what maybe a graphic designer would learn via university and so on (I'm self taught). So it really confused me but of course I wanted to understand and correct myself as best as I could. For my sake and for my computers sake.

Comment: Windows Search couldn't care less how folders are named ;-) So please continue the way you want it, and make sure the naming is relevant to *you*. Personally, when I start something new, I just put everything in one folder, and only when it gets too messy, I start restructuring in subfolders. This is an ongoing process.

Comment: Thanks @Berend! Your advice has been very helping, especially to tame the confusion the was on going in my brain. Haha but yeah, I was shocked because I thought it didn't really matter and what wasn't allowed would be something Windows tells you that you can't put. Ah yes, same for some folders but when I have different reasons like maybe a project, I like making subfolders to start me of somewhere. To each their own I guess? :')